# Geolocation Null in lat and long

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have had issue today in one application where Geolocation is not working. Even on this page http://slaveryfootprint.org/survey/#where_do_you_live . When you enter a location , its showing null lattiude and longitude. Even though it search for autolocation, it can point the right location. and it happened all if a sudden today which was working fine since yestrday night and when I see in console it is returning null lat and long and null for city and I did not change the code at all. Did google map api changed something. or do I need to update jquery?

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.4&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation is opt in.  If you (or one of your users) decline to allow your location to be shared, the geolocation will return null (you should write code to handle that condition).

Note that this:
    http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.4&sensor=false

Is obsolete.  v3.4 of the API has been retired for some time now.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning

The earliest version that is currently available (which is what you get with a request for 3.4) is 3.8.

Comment: That site was working well till yesterday, and it has all the condition to handle user location, even if he deny autolocation , he can type manulay as you can see it in the page. but I am not able to pint he location on map for some reason. I dont know what happened to the API's? event the mobile version of same site is not working.

Comment: here is just a small piece of code:    getLocation: function(){
        var self = this;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                       
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                        //console.log(latlng);
                        self.geocode({"latLng":latlng});
                         AppFacade.userModel.set({"lat": pos.coords.latitude});
                        AppFacade.userModel.set({"lng": pos.coords.longitude});

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that the link you provided was your site that exhibited the problem.  Is it?  It is requesting permission for my location, if I deny that I don't get a map.

Comment: Also, your "small piece of code" is unreadable in the comments, please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: yes if you deny that you get a map but it will not pin your location, you have to manualy type in your location/city to pin the location of map, which will be a flag on map. it suddenly stopped working since morning, its mobile site, local and everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The geolocating with google-maps works fine for me, I get the correct result in IE, because for IE you call `AppFacade.userModel.set()` already in views.js,Line#503 with the results from google.

Later you run a query on Yahoo's geo.placefinder, but when I run the query at the YQL-console I get "service unavailabe", so `AppFacade.userModel.set()` in views.js,Line#583 will not be executed, because the query was not successfull.

But I can't tell you why the YUI-service is unavailable.